# Select columns with the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select customer names with the same zip code but I can't seem to get the correct result. The correct rows that are meant to be returned are 11. I seem to be getting 14 using the following:

```
SELECT a.customer_first_name, a.customer_last_name, a.customer_zip FROM customers a
UNION
SELECT b.customer_first_name, b.customer_last_name, b.customer_zip FROM customers b
```

From here I'm kinda stuck. I know that both statements are the same but this is the basis of where I got to.

I was going to use something along the lines of:

```
WHERE a.customer_zip=b.customer_zip
```

But of course this doesn't work and is kind of irrelevant.

Customers table:

[image: Customers table]

Any help would be much appreciated. If I've missed anything and/or this comes across unclear, then I apologise. Thanks.

**Edit:** The correct result should be 11 rows (which I can't seem to achieve).

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a test script that we could use to reproduce the problem (i.e. the DDL to create the table and the DML to generate some sample data).  And then tell us which of the rows that are currently being returned are the rows that you want to exclude and why.  We don't have your data so we have no idea what rows are returned, which of those rows you want to exclude, or why so we can only speculate about what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_first_name, customer_last_name, customer_zip
FROM customers where customer_zip in 
  (SELECT customer_zip FROM customers
   GROUP BY customer_zip
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: @Xiy well, I didn't see it before (promised), but that's just the "implementation" of Diego's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
select customer_zip
from customers 
group by customer_zip
having count(customer_zip)>1
```

edit:

this will give a list of duplicate ZIPs. based on it, you can esily find the customers with those zips with a select * from customers where customer_zip in (previous_query)